# Why does tidyverse::map not work with two lists in one tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, seq

I am trying to count how many days in column `dias_trabajo` are in `dias_evaluar`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

This is the mininal reprex:

```
tibble(
  dias_trabajo = list(seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-22"), by = "day"), seq(ymd("2021-01-04"), ymd("2021-01-22"), by = "day")),
  dias_evaluar = list(seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-07"), by = "day"))
) %>% 
  mutate(
    trabajo = map(dias_trabajo, function(x) x %in% dias_evaluar) %>% map_int(sum)
  )
```

The above code gives zeros at `trabajo`.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  dias_trabajo dias_evaluar trabajo
  <list>       <list>         <int>
1 <date [22]>  <date [7]>         0
2 <date [19]>  <date [7]>         0
```

I expect the column `trabajo` to be: first row: 7, second row: 4.

I tried with only one line and it works:

```
seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-22"), by = "day") %in% seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-07"), by = "day") %>% sum()
```

gives. It is the expected result for the first row.

```
[1] 7
```

Comment: [`map2`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html). You have two lists `dias_trabajo`and `dias_evaluar`

Comment: Could you please post and answer?, I will choose your answer as the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two lists as input `dias_trabajo` and `dias_evaluar` you need to use [`map2`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

  
tb %>% 
  mutate(
    trabajo = map2_dbl(.x = dias_trabajo, .y = dias_evaluar, ~sum(.x %in% .y))
    )

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  dias_trabajo dias_evaluar trabajo
  <list>       <list>         <int>
1 <date [22]>  <date [7]>         7
2 <date [19]>  <date [7]>         4
```

data:

```
tb <- tibble(
        dias_trabajo = list(seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-22"), by = "day"), seq(ymd("2021-01-04"), ymd("2021-01-22"), by = "day")),
        dias_evaluar = list(seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2021-01-07"), by = "day"))
      )
```